# Intuition behind the entropy definition

Tags: information-retrieval

The definition of information entropy is defined below:

[image]

This looks fine but I got no intuition why it is defined this way. Could any one share their ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: If you've time, pls. refer section 1.6 "Information Theory" from PRML, Bishop. (I need to revise, and may post an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls. refer Pattern recognition and Machine Learning for details - section 1.6: Information Theory.

[image]

Left graph is ***Information***(*events*) vs *Probability*. And the right graph is ***Expected Information***/(*Uncertainity*) vs *Probability*.

If we look *carefully* at the left graph; the variation at either extremes of the curve dies down, representing less change. Translated in current context, it means not much Information flows-in at extremes.

Staying with the left curve, it's *somewhere in the middle* (45-degree, from vertex) where there's relatively more "meat" in the sense that *more change happens/ translated, more information flows-in*.

Same thing is shown by the right curve: at two extremes, Change/ **Expected Information** is *low at extremes*, and highest at *centre*.

A crude Graph using Excel:

[image]

Comment: so from the left figure, the bigger probability actually has smaller h(x) , i.e. fewer information. How do I perceive that higher probability is associated with fewer information?

Comment: My response was too long. Pls. refer the (edited) _Answer_ for response.

Comment: Equation: **p log(p)** _for all_ p in [0, 1] _interval_; it'll be zero if either _p=0 or p=1_, and maximum with _p=1/2_ i.e. (1/2)* log(1/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading your post, now my question becomes why would small probability correspond to high information? Any ideas?

Comment: **Information** is **degree of surprise** and we're **more surprised** on learning about events that're highly **improbable**. And so, _Lower probability_ (values) of event's occurrence maps to _higher information_ (values) and vice-versa. Regards

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a tree node of variable X with n branches where each branch has a depth relative to it's probability. The more balanced your tree at node X is, the higher it's entropy will be at X.

For n=2 the highest entropy is if the probability of each of the two branches is 0.5:
[image]